# MongoDb can't create database from windows command line

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried creating a new Database with mongoDb on windows command line and i got this problem

`use school`
mongoDb switched to school but when i try to confirm that the database has been created database is not displayed along with the other databsses

`show dbs`
returns `local` the default database but the newly created database is not shown and when i tried to insert data into it says `school is not defined`.

why can't i create a new database

Comment: IIRC, the db doesn't actually get created until you put something in it - either a record, or configuration settings

Comment: @theGleep thanks, but when i tried to insert data it says database is not defined. I tried to insert the data from the command line

Comment: @theGleep thanks, you were right. i was inserting the data the wrong way. i inserted it using the right commands and the database got created. thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  Always glad to help!